# How do you move an envelope to a specific point?

Tags: java, geotools

```
Point p = /*a point*/;
ReferencedEnvelope envelope = mapPane.getDisplayArea();
/*envelope.moveTo or something like that? */
mapPane.setDisplayArea(envelope);
```

How can I move the envelope so that the center position is the position of the given point? All I see are "expand"-methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a new envelope centred on your new point:

```
ReferencedEnvelope env = fr.getMapPane().getDisplayArea();
double x,y;//new centre
double w2 = env.getWidth()/2.0;
double h2 = env.getHeight()/2.0;
Coordinate c = new Coordinate(x,y);
ReferencedEnvelope renv = new ReferencedEnvelope(c.x-w2,c.x+w2,c.y-h2,c.y+h2,env.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
```